# Can you check if a method from your library is referenced at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a library and it is crucial that a shutdown method from the library is called before host program termination. Normally people would just read documentation and put the call into a place where they told to place it, however new people recently have been forgetting to call shutdown method which causes weird errors that are difficult to diagnose.

So my idea was to ensure that the method in question has a reference, and if not, it would throw an error at compile time. Is something like that possible to achieve? Is it in

Method is static and is not supposed to be called via reflection so a simple check is enough, no need to check for inheritance and such.

Comment: Any chance you can just implement your library using `IDisposable` so a `using` block at the top level can automatically call your shutdown method?

Comment: And a `finally` so that the CLR might at least *attempt* to run it if someone forgets.

Comment: Even a method call doesn't seem like a great thing to rely on when the computer could crash, the program could crash, or the user could terminate the application forcefully.

Comment: You absolutely cannot assume any clean-up code will run at the end. You cannot run code when the computer suddenly loses power, etc. You should spend time looking to move any code required for correctness into code that runs during *startup*.

Comment: See for example how database systems run *recovery* during startup rather than assuming they can always get a clean shutdown.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts unfortunately no, as not everything would need to be running just in a single using statement

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama a product that would use the library would most likely be a plugin that can be loaded/unloaded multiple times per session. Now normally host program would take responsibility for cleaning up everything after the plugin but it does not and it's not possible to affect it. Funnily enough, library resolves this problem and makes cleanup automatic but it still relies on that single shutdown call that the master plugin has to call. Now I could detect leaks in a subsequent run but I consider it last resort. And if PC has crashed so had the host program so it's whatever.